# Using both maildir and .forward for postfix

Tags: email, postfix

I have a postfix server for handling mail, and trying to finalize my user configuration.

- If I put a `.forward` file in a user home directory to redirect his mail, **it works**.
- If I remove it, to use the `maildir` with dovecot, **it works**.

I'm looking for a way to do both : save the mail in `maildir` **and** forward it to an other address (for backup).

Is it possible without putting it directly in `/etc/mail/aliases` ?
I would like to keep a per-user configuration as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dead simple.  Put a second entry in the `.forward` file that causes delivery to the maildir.  Or just list the user in xyr own `.forward` file.  `man 8 local` for details.

Comment: Ok, adding a second entry with `\username` does it.